# Input code on line 28 will not work

Tags: java, input

The input code on line 28 wont work, what is wrong? When I run, it works up until line 28 then the program quits. The program compiles without errors. The program asks the user for their age, gender, first and last name and if they are older than 20 if they are married. If the user is under 20 the program will not ask if they are married.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Gender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //asking the users age, name, and gender 
        System.out.print("What is your gender (M or F): ");
        String gender = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String FirstName = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String LastName = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        int Age = Input.nextInt();

        if (Age >= 20) {  
            System.out.print("Are you married " + FirstName + " (Y or N): ");
            String AreYouMarried = Input.nextLine(); // << PROBLEM

            if (AreYouMarried == "Y") {
                if(gender == "M") {
                    System.out.println("Then I shal call you Mr." + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
                }
                else if(gender == "F") {
                    System.out.println("Then I shal call you Ms." + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
                }
            }
        }
        if(Age < 20) {
            System.out.print("Then I shall call you " + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What does "wont work" mean and which one is 28?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please pin-point the problem area. Which is line 20??

Comment: the program stops working as soon as it reaches that part of the code.

Comment: @JamesNelson what part of the code?

Comment: @JamesNelson It doesn't stop working, just your string `==` comparisons (in the way you coded them) will probably all fail.

Comment: In future, please note that 'stops working' means next-to-nothing and that SO code has no line numbers displayed.

Comment: Its the comparison you are doing. Use .equals()

Comment: The program dosn't reach the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

1. This is not the right way to compare strings in Java:

   ```
   AreYouMarried == "Y"
   ```

   Use the following:

   ```
   "Y".equals(AreYouMarried)
   ```

   The same applies to the gender comparisons.
2. Don't mix calling `nextInt` and `nextLine` in same program.
   That causes more problems. Stick to using only one of those
   methods in a single program.

Comment: that may be true but the program hasn't even gotten to that step yet. It wont accept input

Comment: Also, there's those pesky corner-cases where you're running the program at a church/registry office or a divorce court.

Comment: @JamesNelson Don't mix calling nextInt and nextLine. That causes this problem. Stick to only one of those methods. E.g. use nextLine only.

Comment: @JamesNelson When you view it that way, the very process of programming is about "pesky" corner-cases :)

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring cause the nextInt() can't read the last character pressed, in your cause ENTER = '\n'.
To solve it, simply call another nextLine() before your asking about mariage. It will be like this..

```
class Gender {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //asking the users age, name, and gender 
    System.out.print("What is your gender (M or F): ");
    String gender = Input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("First name: ");
    String FirstName = Input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Last name: ");
    String LastName = Input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Age: ");
    int Age = Input.nextInt();

    if (Age >= 20) {  
        System.out.print("Are you married " + FirstName + " (Y or N): ");
        Input.nextLine();   
        String AreYouMarried = Input.nextLine(); // << PROBLEM
//HERE CONTINUE CODING
```

and do not forget to change "==" to .equals().
You can't compare Strings like that.

Comment: I have compared strings in the past like that, is this case different in some way?

Comment: @JamesNelson It's not inefficient, rather it's buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `""` with `equals()` method, to compare string content equality use `equals()` method

and

add `Input.nextLine();` after `Syso("Are you married " + FirstName + " (Y or N): ");`

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //asking the users age, name, and gender 
        System.out.print("What is your gender (M or F): ");
        String gender = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String FirstName = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String LastName = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        int Age = Input.nextInt();

        if(Age >= 20){  

            System.out.print("Are you married " + FirstName + " (Y or N): ");
            Input.nextLine();
            String AreYouMarried = Input.nextLine(); 

            if(AreYouMarried.equals("Y")){
                if(gender.equals("M") ){
                    System.out.println("Then I shal call you Mr." + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
                }else if(gender.equals("F") ){
                    System.out.println("Then I shal call you Ms." + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("XYZ msg.");
            }
        }

        if(Age < 20){
            System.out.print("Then I shall call you " + FirstName + " " + LastName + ".");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: It dosn't fix the problem. it might help if you run the program.

Comment: @JamesNelson Can you please tell issue? your code working fine at my end.

Comment: It may be the IDE i'm using what are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse, but it is not IDE issue.

Comment: Please tell me what you are putting input, if you put married as `N` it will display nothing because you not handled condition for `M`

Comment: what you are putting in `Are you married James (Y or N):` Y or N?

Comment: as soon as the IDE JGrasp shows Are you married James (Y or N): the program quits and I don't have the chance to input anything

Comment: @JamesNelson Ok have you added `System.out.print("Are you married " + FirstName + " (Y or N): ");
Input.nextLine();String AreYouMarried = Input.nextLine();

Comment: @JamesNelson I have edited my question you just past that part, it will work for you

Comment: I fixed the original problem but now when I input anything the program quits

Comment: @JamesNelson at what input your program quit If your input is `N` for married it will quit without showing msg you have to handle condition

Comment: the program quits when I input Y or N or anything else.

Comment: @JamesNelson I have edited my answer use that code, and let us know if you are still facing any issue

Comment: are you sure its not an IDE issue?

Comment: yes IDE don't have such type of issue, you have to debug your code line by line and need to find execution flow of your code and trace issue.